# Parameters passed by value, still changed within the function?

Tags: c#, function, parameters

I have a question regarding parameters passed by value in C#: There is a function which is called to compare two complex objects "Umfrage" using memory stream, TeamId should be excluded from that comparison:

```
public static bool CompareSurveys(Umfrage obj, Umfrage obj1)
    {
        obj.TeamId = null;
        obj1.TeamId = null;

        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (obj == null || obj1 == null)
            {
                if (obj == null && obj1 == null)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter(null, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.Clone));
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memStream, obj);
            byte[] b1 = memStream.ToArray();
            memStream.SetLength(0);

            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memStream, obj1);
            byte[] b2 = memStream.ToArray();

            if (b1.Length != b2.Length)
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < b1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (b1[i] != b2[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When I call the method and pass the parameters by value, however, TeamId is set to null anyway. How is that possbile when only the value is passed?

```
Survey.TeamId = "1";
Debug.WriteLine(Survey.TeamId);
if (ModelValidator.CompareSurveys(@survey, Survey))
{
    return BadRequest("No changes were applied");
}
Debug.WriteLine(Survey.TeamId);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Assuming `Umfrage` is a class,  then although you may be passing the reference by value it's still a reference.  Any change you make will be to the same object other areas of your code presumably also have a reference to.

Comment: Thank you very much, that should be it :) Sorry I didn't recognise there was already a question like mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function parameters are two Objects.

If you change some object property in this function these properties will be changed outside the function.

But if in your  function you do
`obj = new Umfrage();` and will change properies all properties won't be changed outside.